# Getting "BlockCountExceedsLimit" exception while using log4net.Appender.AzureAppendBlobAppender

Tags: log4net, azure-web-app-service

I'm using `log4net.Appender.AzureAppendBlobAppender` to log my web app's info & errors. Sometimes I'm getting the "BlockCountExceedsLimit" exception. It is due to the append blob accepts only 50,000 block commits after that it through the exception (Conflict (409)). I have checked the code and found that it waits for the 512 log events and flush each log entry separately to the append blob. So, we can log only 50,000 log entries in a day.

Can anyone please help me on this? Does anyone know any alternate for this?

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the code to a little bit to append the blob, once the buffer reaches the threshold value (512 log entries) it'll flush the log entries in single commit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using [log4net.Appender.Azure](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.Appender.Azure) nuget package. As you can see under [AzureAppendBlobAppender.cs](https://github.com/stemarie/log4net.Azure/blob/master/log4net.Azure/AzureAppendBlobAppender.cs):

```
    private static string Filename(string directoryName)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}.entry.log.xml",
                             directoryName,
                             DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd",
                                                             DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
    }
```

Per my understanding, you could follow [AzureAppendBlobAppender.cs](https://github.com/stemarie/log4net.Azure/blob/master/log4net.Azure/AzureAppendBlobAppender.cs) to write your custom `AzureAppendBlobAppender` and adjust the `Filename`,`SendBuffer` methods to meet your requirement.

> I'm using log4net.Appender.AzureAppendBlobAppender to log my web app's info & errors.

Since you use azure web app to host your application, you could use the built-in Application Logging (Blob), and azure side would help you generate the logs hourly. You could log into Azure Portal, choose your web app, enable application logging (Blob), set the logging level to Information, details you could follow [Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log#enablediag).

For your application, you could use the following code to log info and errors.

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("xxxxx");

System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("xxxxx");
```